# Convert dictionary keys with dotted names to nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I look for similar keys in a dictionary and transform them into a sub-dictionary, knowing the key value pairs are separated using a "."?

Example:

```
d = {"book.title": "abc", "book.content": "def", "author": "ghi"}
```

expected output:

```
 {"book": {"title": "abc", "content": "def"}, "author": "ghi"}
```

Comment: Use loops. The answer is always to use loops.

Comment: Will there always be at most one dot in the key, or can there be multiple levels?

Comment: Only one dot / level of depth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink it. Loop over dictionary keys, split the dotted names, and construct a new dictionary whenever a name is split.

```py
data_in = {"book.title": "abc", "book.content": "def", "author": "ghi"}

data_out = {}
for key, value in data_in.items():
    if "." in key:
        key1, key2 = key.split(".", maxsplit=1)
        if key1 not in data_out:
            data_out[key1] = {}
        data_out[key1][key2] = value
    else:
        data_out[key] = value

assert data_out == {"book": {"title": "abc", "content": "def"}, "author": "ghi"}
```

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make this a little easier, removing the need for the `if key1 not in data_out:` check.

Comment: [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) is probably the easiest way of doing this if you don't have strong performance requirements. Also this can pretty easily be made more uniform (and accept arbitrary depth) by using `*keys, leaf = key.split('.')`, then you can just iterate `keys` to create the nested dicts, and finally set the `leaf` to the value.

Comment: @Masklinn I think that would be good as an additional answer.

Comment: good point, [wrote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75734554/8182118).

Answer (score 2):

For a more generic alternative of @shadowtalker's version:

```py
data_in = {"book.title": "abc", "book.content": "def", "author": "ghi"}

data_out = {}
for key, value in data_in.items():
    cur = data_out
    *keys, leaf = key.split('.')
    for k in keys:
        cur = cur.setdefault(k, {})
    cur[leaf] = value

assert data_out == {"book": {"title": "abc", "content": "def"}, "author": "ghi"}
```

this handles arbitrary depth dotted keys, though might be a bit less efficient as it eagerly creates dicts at every level of recursion (I think cpython has a dicts freelist so hopefully most of those are cheap / free).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use defaultdict, you can try to split the keys and check their length. If the length is 1, you can just append it. If not, split the key and create a nested dictionary which can be inserted in your new dictionary:

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    
    data_in = {"book.title": "abc", "book.content": "def", "author": "ghi"}
    data_out = defaultdict(dict)
    
    for key, value in data_in.items():
        keys = key.split('.')
        if len(keys) == 1:
            data_out[keys[0]] = value
        else:
            data_out[keys[0]][keys[1]] = value
    
    print(data_out)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code also handles nested stuff, such as  `"book.content.table_of_contents" : "foo"`.

```
input_dict = {"book.title": "abc", "book.content": "def", "author": "ghi", "poot.slap.whoop": "donk", "poot.slap.foo": "aeiou"}

def add_to_dict(dictionary, keys, value):
    """Add a value to a dictionary with nested keys."""
    if len(keys) == 1:
        dictionary[keys[0]] = value
    else:
        sub_dict_key = keys[0]
        sub_dict = dictionary.setdefault(sub_dict_key, {})
        add_to_dict(sub_dict, keys[1:], value)

output_dict = {}

for key, value in input_dict.items():
    parts = key.split(".")
    add_to_dict(output_dict, parts, value)

print(output_dict)
```

Outputs: `{'book': {'title': 'abc', 'content': 'def'}, 'author': 'ghi', 'poot': {'slap': {'whoop': 'donk', 'foo': 'aeiou'}}}`

I haven't test it thoroughly, but this should hopefully do the trick. Good luck out there.

Comment: Nice demo of recursion, and a nice counterpoint to [Masklinn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75734554/2954547).